# Converting Raster datasets into layers using ArcPy/ModelBuilder?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, modelbuilder, raster-conversion

I am new to ArcGIS and ArcPy (just started using them on Wednesday).

I am using a model to create a Point Density plot from a Shape File, with the output being a Raster dataset.

I want to convert the Raster dataset into a new layer and modify the properties.

Is there a function that converts Raster datasets into layers, or is there another way to do it?

It is clear the the model is just a starting point, and that I have to add Python code for it to do what I want it to do.

Comment: When you say convert it to a layer, do you mean vector data or literally just a raster layer?

Comment: Literally just a raster layer.  Doing it manually, after loading the Shape File, I run the point Density tool, which results in the Raster Layer.  Then I right click on the Raster Layer I choose Properties and change the properties.  Running a model with the Shape file and the Point Density function only results in an output Raster, which I can display, but I want to do further processes with the Raster Layer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The raster equivalent to the Make Feature Layer tool that is often mentioned on this site is [Make Raster Layer (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006t000000):

> Creates a raster layer from an input raster dataset or layer file. The
>   layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist
>   after the session ends unless the layer is saved to disk or the map
>   document is saved.
>
> This tool can be used to make a temporary layer, so you can work with
>   a specified subset of bands within a raster dataset.

There are two ArcPy code samples included as part of the documentation linked to above.

However, I am not certain that this tool was available in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Comment: Thank you.  The MakeRasterLayer_management function is what I was looking for.